# Eclipse CDT Include Folder

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, stdio

I am a C++ newb. I have the Eclipse Luna IDE for Windows 10 and downloaded the Eclipse C/C++ IDE CDT 9.4 plugin. I have some code which has

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

which is giving me "unresolved inclusion". Based on my research it means I do not have some include folder. I cannot find it on my Windows machine and all the help I've found is with ubuntu or Linux-based operating systems. So how do I get this to work? How do I get the folder?

Comment: Look into the folder where the compiler is installed. Then, add that folder to Eclipse "include list".

Comment: @Ripi2 it does not contain an "include" folder. Only ones I have that have "include" are related to java.

Comment: Have you installed a compiler as well? CDT does not come with its own compiler, but requires another one, e. g. MinGW or MinGW64. Then you need to make sure CDT finds the compiler, it should then find the include directories as well.

Comment: *"it does not contain an "include" folder"* See [C/C++ Project Properties, Paths and Symbols, Includes](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_prop_general_pns_inc.htm).

Comment: @Ripi2 That's for the non-standard headers. If you need to include the standard header files there, you've obviously done something wrong.

Comment: @Aconcagua can I still used Eclipse while having MinGW's include folder?

Comment: @GeorgeXavier Not sure what exactly you mean... At first, you will have to install MinGW. Then easiest is including the path to gcc.exe (directory only) in windows' PATH variable. Normally, CDT should find the rest then by itself. If you opt for MinGW 64, earlier you additionally needed to rename one of the exe-files. Not sure any more which one it was – and if if that problem yet persists at all. Might with your outdated eclipse version, though.

Comment: @Aconcagua ok I have the includes folder, now how do I link it to eclipse? I already put the path in the environmental variables.

Comment: @GeorgeXavier The standard libraries should get linked automatically, too. Did you get a linker error? That would surprise me now...

Comment: @Aconcagua nvm the most recent comment, it can find it now. Now I think a completely unassociated binary-not-found error, so header problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to project properties, C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols and for Language GNU C you should see the compiler default include folders.

If not, you might have a path problem.

And i think [This](https://codeyarns.com/2015/10/01/unresolved-inclusion-warning-in-eclipse/) helps you!

Comment: It was not having the minGW "include" folder, Then attaching it to the path I got it working.